# Git - Am I using it correctly?

Tags: git, ubuntu

I've been trying to set up git recently, and I've come across many problems which it is difficult to find solutions to on line, which has lead me to think I may me misunderstanding something about how Git is used.

**The Scenario**

The main site is running on an Ubuntu box, and I also have a test server set up which is almost a duplicate of the live server. There are currently two developers, both developing on a PC. What I wish to do is create a remote repository on the test server, which both developers can push to, and then test their changes to the website normally (through a browser). So far I have set up a local repository and installed Git GUI; the only information I could find to get a remote repo set up (which we can push to) is using:

```
git init --bare
```

I can't find any information about how to "extract" (<-- what's the correct word for this) the repo into it's php directory structure so I can be used through a web browser.

**My Question(s)**

1) Am I doing this correctly? If not what am I mis-understanding, and how do I resolve this?

OR 2) If I am doing this correctly, what do I need to do to "extract" the repo?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you made it halfway there. Yes, you make a new repository on the server, but it's not where the live site lives. The process of using git to manage a website (php or whatever) is [well described here](http://danielmiessler.com/study/git/).

Create the hub repository on the server:

```
$ mkdir website.git && cd website.git
$ git init --bare
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/YOU/website.git/
```

After you create this empty repository, you need to define and enable a post-receive hook that checks the latest tree into your server's DocumentRoot (must already exist, git will not create it for you.)

```
$ mkdir /var/www/www.example.org
$ cat > hooks/post-receive
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/www.example.org git checkout -f
$ chmod +x hooks/post-receive
```

On your first developer's workstation, you add the remote directory to the local config, then push the contents of the local repository to the remote one.

```
git remote add website ssh://home/YOU/website.git/
git push website +master:refs/heads/master
```

when you change things locally and upload changes, do a

```
git push website
```

The second developer should simply clone the remote repository to work locally.

```
git clone ssh://home/YOU/website.git/
```

Of course, your developers will want to keep their repositories in sync. If the main server has new changes due to activity from the other developer, the push will fail, so the developer should pull the latest version and resolve any merge conflicts and try again.

#### Edit:

Here is [another tutorial](http://Looks%20like%20you%20made%20it%20halfway%20there.%20Yes,%20you%20make%20a%20new%20repository%20on%20the%20server,%20but%20it%27s%20not%20where%20the%20live%20site%20lives:) that takes a slightly different approach. Rather than checking out the work tree to your DocumentRoot with a post-receive hook, it sets up a "prime" repository in the DocumentRoot and pulls the changes in from the "hub" repository after a post-update hook, and it uses a post-commit hook to make sure the "hub" stays in sync in case any changes are made on the live server.

[image: git workflow overview]

Answer (score 1):

What I'm doing in my git setup is the following:

```
git --bare init
```

on the server. Then I clone this repository locally and add it to my git remote repositories so I can push to it.

I think you can use
    **git archive**
to "extract"/export the content of your repository. The bare repository will only contain the .git directory of the repository so you have to use archive to get your stuff out.

What you also can do is just clone the bare repository to where you want it to be e.g. your php directory. Then you have all the files there and can pull the changes from your bare repository.

Answer (score 0):

For dealing with a remote repository I highly recommend http://book.git-scm.com/3_distributed_workflows.html. In your case, the topics **Public git repositories** and **Pushing changes to a public repository**.

As far as extraction (You might mean 'deployment'), it is not supported by git -- 'the stupid content tracker'. The simplest solution to your problem would be to simply symlink `ln -s` into your git repository from wherever you want to extract your project to. This will require your source code to maintain the directory structure of the live project.

If you go with the symlink solution, assuming your repo is in the `~/project` and you want to serve your project from `~/public_html`:

```
$ cd ~/public_html
$ ln -s ../project .
```